# Regular expression for a string literal in flex/lex

Tags: c, regex, lex, string-literals, flex-lexer

I'm experimenting to learn flex and would like to match string literals. My code currently looks like:

```
"\""([^\n\"\\]*(\\[.\n])*)*"\""        {/*matches string-literal*/;}
```

I've been struggling with variations for an hour or so and can't get it working the way it should. I'm essentially hoping to match a string literal that can't contain a new-line (unless it's escaped) and supports escaped characters.

I am probably just writing a poor regular expression or one incompatible with flex. Please advise!

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! All your comments were very helpful. The regex that has finally worked for me is a variant of the one used in the C specification linked by codadict (and explained by Jonathan): \"(\\(.|\n)|[^\\"\n])*\"

Comment: Since you found Jonathan's answer helpful, consider adding an upvote for his answer.

Comment: By the way: nowhere in your question do you specify what language's string literals you're interested in. It's a very good idea to put the language you're asking about in one of the question's tags.

Answer (score 132):

A string consists of a quote mark

```
"
```

followed by zero or more of either an escaped anything

```
\\.
```

or a non-quote character, non-backslash character

```
[^"\\]
```

and finally a terminating quote

```
"
```

Put it all together, and you've got

```
\"(\\.|[^"\\])*\"
```

The delimiting quotes are escaped because they are Flex meta-characters.

Comment: This doesn't handle escaping, unfortunately. So this would incorrectly lex `"\""`

Comment: You must have missed "zero or more of an escaped anything"?

Comment: There are several problems with this answer. First, it's not a valid flex pattern.  The leading and trailing double-quotes need to be escaped because otherwise flex treats them as meta-characters.  So the pattern should be (perhaps) \"(\\.|[^"])*\" .  Second, that pattern still doesn't work.  For example, it gets this input wrong: "\\\\" .  Third, it doesn't meet the original question's requirement of disallowing newlines.

Comment: As a regex, this is totally correct. Except for the newline thing, which is easily fixed by replacing `.` with `[^\n]` and `[^"]` with `[^"\n]`. It certainly should match `"\\\\"` too, since the repetition will match the quote `"`, then the escaped slash `\\ `, then the next escaped slash `\\ `, then the terminating quote `"`.  The pattern certainly works for me outside of the scope of flex.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it works outside the scope of flex.  The question was about flex.  If the lexer produced by flex sees `"\\\\"foo"`, it will match the entire input, instead of just matching the `"\\\\"` part, because the character class doesn't exclude backslashes.

Comment: @robmayoff is correct. This will incorrectly match all of `"\\"a"` (as: `quote`, `not-quote`, `backslash-dot-anything`, `not-quote`, `quote`). The regex should say `[^"\\]`, not `[^"]`.

Comment: There's actually one more subtlety here since . won't match a \n. So the final flex pattern needed with escaping is  \"(\\.|\\\n|[^"\\])*\"

Comment: lol upvoted not b/c it's in flex, but I've been looking for a regex that matches a string literal.

Answer (score 29):

For a single line... you can use this:

```
\"([^\\\"]|\\.)*\"  {/*matches string-literal on a single line*/;}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Comment: Shouldn't we make sure that the starting quote is not preceded by a backslash (is escaped) ?

Comment: If it is preceded by a backslash, it should match no other rule and thus signal an error.

Answer (score 9):

How about using a start state...

```
int enter_dblquotes = 0;

%x DBLQUOTES
%%

\"  { BEGIN(DBLQUOTES); enter_dblquotes++; }

<DBLQUOTES>*\" 
{ 
   if (enter_dblquotes){
       handle_this_dblquotes(yytext); 
       BEGIN(INITIAL); /* revert back to normal */
       enter_dblquotes--; 
   } 
}
         ...more rules follow...
```

It was similar to that effect (flex uses `%s` or `%x` to indicate what state would be expected. When the flex input detects a quote, it switches to another state, then continues lexing until it reaches another quote, in which it reverts back to the normal state.

Comment: @Samoz: Not really, it's actually used in languages where string literals are used, it eats up what's between a beginning quote and an end quote, even if there's extra quotes inside it hence the usage of switching states in order to chew up the quotes...

Comment: The flex manual contains a full example (in terms of flex usage) of parsing C-style strings: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Start-Conditions.html .  Search for "quoted strings" on that page.

Answer (score 3):

Paste my code snippet about handling string in flex, hope inspire your thinking.

Use [Start Condition](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) to handle string literal will be more scalable and clear.

```
%x SINGLE_STRING

%%

\"                          BEGIN(SINGLE_STRING);
<SINGLE_STRING>{
  \n                        yyerror("the string misses \" to termiate before newline");
  <<EOF>>                   yyerror("the string misses \" to terminate before EOF");
  ([^\\\"]|\\.)*            {/* do your work like save in here */}
  \"                        BEGIN(INITIAL);
  .                         ;
}
```

Comment: How do I save the string to yytext using this method ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what we use in [Zolang](https://github.com/Zolang/Zolang) for single line string literals with embedded templates `${...}`

`\"(\$\{.*\}|\\.|[^\"\\])*\"`

Comment: It would be able to match this properly:

`"Hello ${some + "world"}"`

Answer (score 0):

An answer that arrives late but which can be useful for the next one who will need it:

```
\"(([^\"]|\\\")*[^\\])?\"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer would be improved with text explaining *how* it works and *how* it is different.