# How to recognize a string literal for a scanner in lex?

Tags: regex, lex

Ok, I have been trying to find a regular expression in lex that will recognize a C-like string literal in an input string. eg. in `printf("stackoverflow")`, "stackoverflow" should be recognized as a string literal.
I have been trying the following:

```
"[.]+"
["][.]+["]
\"[.]+\"
[\"][.]+[\"]
"""[.]+"""
```

None of these is working. The lexeme recognized each time is " alone. What should I do?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for a string literal in flex/lex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039795/regular-expression-for-a-string-literal-in-flex-lex)

Answer (score 3):

Simple, try this:

```
\".*\"     printf("STRING[%s]", yytext);
\'.*\'     printf("STRING[%s]", yytext);
```

When compiled and run, a quick test shows it correctly parses strings like

```
"hello world!"
STRING["hello world!"]
'hello world!'
STRING['hello world!']
'john\'s cat'
STRING['john\'s cat']
'mary said "hello!"'
STRING['mary said "hello!"']
"frank said \"goodbye!\""
these are words "which contain" a string
these are words STRING["which contain"] a string
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find these links helpful

- [ANSI C grammar, Lex
  specification](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html)
- [ANSI C Yacc grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html)