# Make flex handle escaped newlines automatically

Tags: lex, lexer, lexical-analysis

I am looking for a rule in flex that handles the escaped newlines and gives me a token ignoring that newline.

Eg:

I have a rule in my lex specification like:

```
\"(\.|[^\"])*\"
```

to capture all the string literals. This does capture strings from code like:

```
Printf("This is literal")
```

but it doesn't give me the correct token if code is like:

```
printf("This is \
   literal.")
```

What modification I can make to my lex spec to handle this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418181/flex-lex-encoding-strings-with-escaped-characters/5423131?s=5|38.8871#5423131

Answer (score 2):

(F)lex only recognises tokens. Interpreting their contents is up to you.

If you're just recognising a string literal, you can use a regular expression like

```
["]([^"\n]|\\.)*["]
```

But if you want the correct interpretation of the string literal -- according to your language -- you'll need a start condition with appropriate actions.

The usual approach is to get initialise a StringBuffer like object when you see the opening `"`, and change to the string start condition. Non-special characters are just appended to the StringBuffer; escape sequences like `\n` append an appropriate character to the StringBuffer, and `\\\n` does nothing. When the close quote iseen, tje token is actually sent along with the accumulated text.

For more detailed examples, see [Flex / Lex Encoding Strings with Escaped Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5423131/1566221) and [Optimizing flex string literal parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358417/1566221) (and probably many many more).