# Matching HTML-style comments with lex/flex

Tags: parsing, lex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I wish to match COMMENT as `<!--C-->` so:

1. It starts with `<!--`
2. Ends with **the first** `-->`
3. C - could be anything (including tabs, line breaks, etc.)

I got a problem with ending in the first `-->`

and thus obviously this solution doesn't work:
 `COMMENT (\<!--((.|(\n))*)--\>)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at how C strings can be matched: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039795/regular-expression-for-a-string-literal-in-flex-lex The solution should be similar.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Thanks but I still can't figure it out. Doesn't seem that similar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
COMMENT    <!--([^-]|-[^-]|--+[^->])*-*-->
```

I know that's a bit of a pain to read. It translates to:

An `<!--` followed by any number of:

- anything other than a dash, or
- a single dash followed by anything other than a dash (including `>`), or
- two or more dashes, followed by anything other than a dash or a `>`

and then finally two or more dashes followed by a `>`