# PHP - Convert strings to key value array

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with converting chars from a text file to a key value array.
It ignore the spaces.

My text is like this:

```
type="lorem" template="lorem_ipsum.phtml" key1="lorem Ipsum" key2="lorem Ipsum" key2="lorem Ipsum"
```

The problem appears near the separator in my preg_match code, I lose the seconds words in key1 or key´2 values!

```
preg_match_all("/([^,= ]+)=([^,= ]+)/", $line_Content, $r);
$myarray = array_combine($r[1], str_replace('" ','',$r[2]));
```

Help!

Comment: What is the possible syntax here? Is the format always *alphanumeric followed by = followed by " followed by anything but " terminated by "*? Or is this more complex HTML-attribute-like syntax?

Comment: Can you please post the whole code?

Comment: @deceze: There is no html in the text, but it contains spaces and the key names key1, key2... My text have always an alphanumeric key, followed by = "text values "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex should match your intended text much better:

```
(\w+)="([^"]*)"
```

A word followed by an equal sign followed by a double quote, then anything up until the next double quote.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]*)"/', $line_Content, $r);
$myarray = array_combine($r[1], $r[2]);
```

Note that this will fail for double quotes inside the double quotes, at which point you'd need escape sequences, at which point regular expressions become quite cumbersome.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2039820/171318 .. If you are using it, your regex would be stable. +1 since it is not *said* that these are indeed attributes of an XML node.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like attributes of an XML/HTML node. Why not letting a `DOMParser` doing our work?

```
$string = 'type="lorem" template="lorem_ipsum.phtml" key1="lorem Ipsum" key2="lorem Ipsum"';
$xml = '<foo ' . $string . ' />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadXML($xml);

$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('foo')->item(0);
foreach($element->attributes as $attr) {
    $result [$attr->name] = $attr->value;
}

var_dump($result);
```

This is useful if you explicitly want to validate that the string is *well formed*. However, if your input isn't XML/HTML that it is not useful.