# How to detect string during lexical analysis?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am using some syntax to detect string during lexical analysis

```
"".*""    return TOK_STRING;
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for a string literal in flex/lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039795/regular-expression-for-a-string-literal-in-flex-lex)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
\".*\"
```

but be aware that <kbd>.</kbd> in flex does not match newlines. And, as @chqrlie mentions in a comment, it *does* match <kbd>"</kbd>, so it will match to the end of the last string, and not the current one.

So a better pattern might be:

```
\"[^"]*\"
```

(`[^"]` matches any character including newlines, except <kbd>"</kbd>).

But then you have no way to include a <kbd>"</kbd> in a string. So you will have to decide what syntax that should be. If you wanted to implement SQL style, with doubled quotes representing a single quote inside a string, you could use

```
\"([^"]|\"\")*\"
```

For the possibly more common backslash escape:

```
\"([^"]|\\(.|\n))*\"
```

Comment: Also be aware that `.` does match `"`, so this is not a proper regular expression to match C string literals.

Comment: how can we go with \n if we want to include in string

Comment: @chqrlie: good point. Expanded the answer, but I think there is no substitute for a good book an regular expressions.