# JLEX lexical generator error: unterminated string at the end of the line

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, jlex

I am generating lexical analyzer with JLEX. I found a regular expression for string literal from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039795/regular-expression-for-a-string-literal-in-flex-lex) and used it in .jflex file same of other expressions. but it gives me this error :
**unterminated string at the end of the line** 
StringLiteral =  \"(\\.|[^"\\])*\"

can anyone help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you copied is for (f)lex, which uses a slightly different syntax for regular expressions. In particular, (f)lex treats `"` as an ordinary character inside bracketed classes, so `[^"\\]` is a character class matching anything other than (`^`) a quotation mark (`"`) or a backslash (`\\`).

However, in JFlex, the `"` is a quoting character, whether outside or inside brackets. So the `"` in the character class is unterminated. Hence the error message.

So you need to backslash-escape it:

```
StringLiteral = \"(\\.|[^\"\\])*\"
```

See [the JFlex manual chapter on regular expressions](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/modern/java/JLex/current/manual.html#SECTION2.3.2) for details