# How do i parse out the row and column values from an excel formula string?

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, formula

If I have a string in javascript like `=sum(A1,B2)` or an example variation like `= sum( C1, ZX2)` . The combinations of cells could be anything. I need a function to parse out the two parameters. In Javascript using regex.

Comment: Can your formulae include absolute references (eg $A3, A$3 or $A$3) or references to cells on other worksheets (eg 'Sheet 1'!C5) or even other workbooks ([C:\Excel\Workbook2.xls]Sheet1!A1)? Or might they include references in R1C1 format?

Comment: Possible duplicate [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897906/is-this-the-regex-for-matching-any-cell-reference-in-an-excel-formula)

Answer (score 1):

This regexp matches those strings:
`\s?([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+[0-9]+)`

In JavaScript you'd use this:
`string.match('([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/')` 
It returns an array of matches, in this case it would return ["A1,A2"], you'd still need to explode the string at ','

Comment: How can this be used in javascript to get for example A1 and A2 from a formula string =sum(A1,A2) ?

Comment: `string.match('([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*?([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/')` Returns an array of matches, in this case it would return ["A1,A2"], you'd still need to explode the string at ','.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\[A-Z]+[0-9]+)\s*,\s*(\[A-Z]+[0-9]+)/
```

should work on your examples. Will you also have to handle ranges like `A12:C34`?