# Why is the substring method behaving in this manner?

Tags: javascript, substring

```
var str ="20110725";
var dd = str.substring(6);
var mm = str.substring(4,2);
var yyyy = str.substring(0,3);
alert(dd );//25
alert(mm);//11
alert(yyyy );//2011
```

Instead of the above output, I expected "25" as date, "07" as month and "2011" as year. Please correct me.

Comment: So, now you have a new problem - you should probably accept an answer and create a new stackoverflow question fon the month[mon] business.  I know the answer to that - but I don't want to muddy these waters.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `substr()`, not `substring()`.  They're different.

Comment: not much difference. except it would be a little harder to read.

Comment: @Joseph: they are far from the same; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring

Comment: I know they are different... I didn't deny it... but they are similar: substr(startPosition,endPosition) substring(startPosition,length). I use these on a a daily basis. substr is harder to read in this case because instead of (4,2) for month (length of two chracters) it would be (4,6) (positions 4 and 6). that is harder to read imo and non-intuitive.

Comment: But, in this case, the only one it's affecting is the "mm" calculation.

Comment: I see.. I misread the posters comments... I thought those three numbers were the desired result :P

Comment: Right, OP is complaining that (4,2) is going from position 4 to position 2 when he wants from position 4 forward 2 positions.  He's using substring() as though it were substr().  I stand by my recommendation. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have

```
var mm = str.substring(4, 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
var mm = str.substring(4, 2)
```

Do:

```
var mm = str.substring(4, 6)
```

Comment: The second parameter is the "up to but not including" value, so it should be "6", not "5".

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You also need a 4, not a 3 for your year.

```
var str ="20110725";
var dd = str.substr(6);
var mm = str.substr(4,2);
var yyyy = str.substr(0,4);
alert(dd );//25
alert(mm);//11
alert(yyyy );//2011
```