# DOM manipulation in Angular directive after sub view rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a directive that will truncate long text in element and show a popover with full text in case truncation take place.

```
See http://plnkr.co/edit/90WP5ISQHG7FXRpetucm?p=preview
```

For text truncation I've used CSS and it works well.
But when I'm trying to access element content I see `{{str.data}}` rather then exact text from the data.

I guess that I need even't that is fired after rendering, but I can't fing any suitable.

So my question how can I run my DOM manipulation after sub view get rendered?

The only solution I've found so far is using timeout, but I think that there is better solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just a simple rollover to show the remainder text? That's simple CSS.

```
.truncate-overflow:hover{ width:auto; overflow:visible; }
```

If not that, I would suggest storing the data into two separate pieces of data by limiting the string length. See how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463674/1327678

Comment: Not exactly, I need to show bootstrap help-tooltip that will contain the full string, only if overflow take place.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by performing my DOM manipulation inside `mouseover` instead of `link` method.

```
See http://plnkr.co/edit/90WP5ISQHG7FXRpetucm?p=preview for more details.
```

PS. Popover position is incorrect because plnkr overrides css manipulation and do not set top and left.