# Jquery credit card Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate credit card using jquery, Limit 16 numbers, automatically add a space after 4 numbers when typing numbers. The credit card number like

**4444 4444 4444 4444**

How to validate like this using jquery

Comment: You can use jquery masking, have a look at this: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/masked-input

Comment: Take a look at card.js at this: http://jessepollak.github.io/card/

Comment: Using jquery mask, 4444 4444 4444 4444, how to limit 16 numbers

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question contains nothing about this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with just jQuery, and not card.js (though it seems pretty cool) this code should take care of it:

```
$('.credit').on('input', function(){
    var number = $(this).val();
    number = number.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1').trim().substring(0, 19);
    $(this).val(number);
});
```

Help from [How to insert space every 4 characters for IBAN registering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260238/how-to-insert-space-every-4-characters-for-iban-registering) and [Javascript trim a string to length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463658/javascript-trim-a-string-to-length)