# Short down text, but leave the filetype visible

Tags: jquery, text, short

How can I make this possible?

From **this-is-a-very-long-filename.jpg** to **this-is-a-very-lo [...] .jpg**.

I have searched Google for several minutes now but I can't find any solution to this. Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any specific width you need to have?

Comment: Well, I want to have the ability change the max visible characters like `substring(0,8)+"..."` or something.

Comment: do you absolutely need jQuery to do this?

Comment: Yes. I will expand an jQuery function to my upload page. If the file is too long, the filename continues on a new row. This I don't want. I just want to shorten the filename but keep the filetype intact.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, you can use classic javascript:

```
<script>
  function truncate(n, len) {
      var ext = n.substring(n.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, n.length).toLowerCase();
      var filename = n.replace('.'+ext,'');
      if(filename.length <= len) {
          return n;
      }
      filename = filename.substr(0, len) + (n.length > len ? '[...]' : '');
      return filename + '.' + ext;
  };
  var s = 'this-is-a-very-very-very-long-file-name.jpg';
  console.log(truncate(s, 100)); //this-is-a-very-very-very-long-file-name.jpg
  console.log(truncate(s, 10)); //this-is-a-[...].jpg
  console.log(truncate(s, 4)); //this[...].jpg
</script>
```

Comment: I have one problem though. When I select a file, I'll get **Chamma Swaetty Lobbs.jpg.jpg** as a full filename with your function. When I look at the code I can't see any problems whit it (I'm sort of a JavaScript noob). Can you see the problem? :)

Comment: oh because the file is too short it put it again, let me fix it, sorry about that

Comment: It's okay :) Everyone makes mistakes sometimes ^^ Thanks yet again!

Comment: Read about [the difference between `substr` and `substring`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring). Should be `n.substr(n.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, n.length)`, I suppose. But `substring` with a longer index than the length of the string ends at the original length, so it's not critical here.

Comment: Also it may be better to use `var filename = n.substring(0, n.lastIndexOf('.'))` to get filename. Because `replace('.'+ext, '')` removes **all** occurrences of extension `ext` from a filename. Just make sure that `n.lastIndexOf('.')` is not negative (a case when a dot never occurs in the filename).

Answer (score -2):

use this plugin:

http://papermashup.com/truncate-text-with-the-jtruncate-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't helped me at all :/