# How to grab substring before a specified character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, substring, substr

I am trying to extract everything before the ',' comma. How do I do this in JavaScript or jQuery? I tried this and not working..

```
1345 albany street, Bellevue WA 42344
```

I just want to grab the street address.

```js
var streetaddress= substr(addy, 0, index(addy, '.'));
```

Comment: `addy.split(',', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 587, accepted):

```
const streetAddress = addy.substring(0, addy.indexOf(","));
```

While it’s not the best place for definitive information on what each method does ([MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are better for that) [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is good for introducing you to syntax.

Comment: This will not work if the string being searched does not contain an instance of the search character. It will return an empty string.

Comment: `substr` isn't recommended; should use `substring` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 256):

```
var streetaddress = addy.split(',')[0];
```

Comment: swings and roundabouts - it unnecessarily creates an array, but does at least work if the stop character isn't in the string

Comment: For performance comparison, see: https://jsperf.com/street-array-vs-substr

Comment: previous comment link is dead :/

Comment: As mentioned by @Alnitak, this option is best if the stop character isn't in the string.

Comment: Consider `addy.split(",", 1)[0]` which stops splitting after the first occurrence of `","`.

Answer (score 47):

try this:

```
streetaddress.substring(0, streetaddress.indexOf(','));
```

Comment: Why no love for my answer? If this answer is correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring my answer is as accurate as the accepted answer, and works for starting indices other than 0.

Comment: As pointed out by David G above, possibly because it doesn't work if there is no comma.  The OP may have implied that the string would always have a comma, but in many instances the delimiter is not guaranteed.  See https://jsfiddle.net/13pkp1xn/

Answer (score 41):

```
//split string into an array and grab the first item

var streetaddress = addy.split(',')[0];
```

Also, I'd recommend naming your variables with camel-case(streetAddress) for better readability.

Comment: This is better than the method using indexof, in the scenario where there is no comma character

Comment: You can save some processing and stop splitting at the first "," found by using what @antak posted as a comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22386366/601386: `addy.split(',', 1)[0]`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.

Comment: Using array deconstruction, you could do: `const [streetAddress,] = addy.split(',');`

This is helpful for cases when you want more than one value, such as: `let [callerIdName, callerId] = callerIdString.split('<');`  (original callerIdString format is MCMULLIN,PARKER <+1XXXXXXXXXX>)

Comment: Isn't this answer exactly the same as the answer posted on Oct 30, 2015?

Answer (score 22):

If you like it short simply use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var streetAddress = /[^,]*/.exec(addy)[0];
```

Comment: +1, I think this is a reasonable method, but I took a hint from this and went with `addy.split(',', 1)[0]`

Comment: This method is very nice for example if you want to split on white space: /[^\s]*/.exec(...)

Comment: When the remove substring does not neccesarily exist: `streetAddress = addy.replace(/,.*$/, '');`, this removes everything after the first match (of `,`) only if it exists

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

```
var streetaddress = addy.split(',').shift();
```

**According to MDN Web Docs:**

> The **`shift()`** method removes the **first** element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Indexing with [0] is more efficient than using .shift()

Comment: Warning: if input string doesn't contain comma, it the entire string will be returned.

Answer (score 13):

almost the same thing as David G's answer but without the anonymous function, if you don't feel like including one.

```
s = s.substr(0, s.indexOf(',') === -1 ? s.length : s.indexOf(','));
```

in this case we make use of the fact that the second argument of `substr` is a length, and that we know our substring is starting at 0.

the top answer is **not a generic solution** because of the undesirable behavior if the string doesn't contain the character you are looking for.

if you want correct behavior in a generic case, use this method or David G's method, not the top answer

regex and split methods will also work, but may be somewhat slower / overkill for this specific problem.

Answer (score 9):

```
var newString = string.substr(0,string.indexOf(','));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var streetaddress = addy.substr(0, addy.indexOf('.'));
```

(You should read through a [javascript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp), esp. the part about [String functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the original string untouched if it does not contain the search character then you can use an anonymous function (a closure):

```
var streetaddress=(function(s){var i=s.indexOf(',');
   return i==-1 ? s : s.substr(0,i);})(addy);
```

This can be made more generic:

```
var streetaddress=(function(s,c){var i=s.indexOf(c);
   return i==-1 ? s : s.substr(0,i);})(addy,',');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex as this will give you the string if it matches the requirements. The code would be something like:

```
const address = "1345 albany street, Bellevue WA 42344";
const regex = /[1-9][0-9]* [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+/;
const matchedResult = address.match(regex);

console.log(matchedResult[0]); // This will give you 1345 albany street.
```

So to break the code down. `[1-9][0-9]*` basically means the first number cannot be a zero and has to be a number between `1-9` and the next number can be any number from `0-9` and can occur zero or more times as sometimes the number is just one digit and then it matches a space. `[a-zA-Z]` basically matches all capital letters to small letters and has to occur one or more times and this is repeated.

Comment: regex that is difficult, big mechanism and it has bad performance, we need avoid using it

Answer (score 0):

According to the ESLint rule [prefer-string-slice](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-string-slice.md), here is my implementation using `slice()` :

```
function getStreetAddress(str: string, separator = ','): string {
  const separatorIndex = path.indexOf(separator);

  return separatorIndex === -1 ? str : str.slice(0, separatorIndex);
}
```

It returns the whole string if the separator has not been found.

Worth to mention, as it seems you're trying to parse a kind of CSV file row, this code may work in your case, but not when the street address contains special characters or the separator itself (`,`). To do so, fields in CSV files may be wrapped with quotes, which is not handled in this simple implementation.

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about catching the case where no comma is present, you could just do this:

```
let end = addy.indexOf(",") >= 0 ? addy.indexOf(",") : addy.length;
let streetaddress = addy.substr(0, end);
```

Nobody said it had to go on one line.

Comment: `.indexOf()` returns -1 if the needle is not found. Therefore `addy.length` will never be chosen.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Corrected.