# Read a string until a specific character appears in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading from a list of strings like this:

> April 9, 2012 (2012-04-09) num 0 April 16, 2012 (2012-04-16) num 0
>   April 23, 2012 (2012-04-23) num 0 April 30, 2012 (2012-04-30) num 0
>   May 7, 2012 (2012-05-07) num 0 May 14, 2012 (2012-05-14) num 0 October
>   8, 2012 (2012-10-08)[126] num 0 October 15, 2012 (2012-10-15)[126] num
>   0 October 22, 2012 (2012-10-22)[126] num 0 October 29,
>   2012 (2012-10-29)[126] num 0

I want to read the date until the first parenthesis '(' I've tried:

```
console.log( $(this).text().substring(0,16) );
```

but that only works with the longer months, the rest (like may or june) return part of the rest of the string. Is there a method I could use to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to grab substring before a specified character jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the `indexof(str)` method

```
myStr.substring(0, myStr.indexOf('('))
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I'll add to your answer: here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4YsaR/

Comment: This should be the answer. Ignore mine.

Comment: For those looking at this several years later as an answer to a similar problem, if there was no bracket this would return an empty string. So need to be careful to check the "stop" character exists first!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a=$(this).text();
console.log( a.substr(0, a.indexOf('(')) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log( $(this).text().substring(0, $(this).text().indexOf('(') );`