# Slicing words from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that has words and spaces,

```
var version = "One Forty Six 1.1 V2 (10 kilo / 20 kilo) (2000 - 2005)"
```

I want to extract

```
One Forty Six 1.1 V2
```

out of it.
What is the best practice of doing it? How can i use **.slice** to extract what i am looking for?

Comment: Do you want to extract anything that's not in parenthesis? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think you need a function that would be worked with several strings right?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you want, it is impossible to answer. Do you want first 20 characters? Any characters not in parentheses? Anything up to and including the word "V2"? I suspect I might know which, but you need to define it, we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: why do you want to extract what you already have?  or you want to extract something generic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grab substring before a specified character jQuery or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript) and [Read a string until a specific character appears in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363516) and [How to get sub string before special character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split on `(` to get the result. split returns an array and will contain 2 substrings separated splitted on all occurrences of `(`. We need to get the first part of the string so we use `[0]` to get that.

```js
var version = "One Forty Six 1.1 V2 (10 kilo / 20 kilo) (2000 - 2005)";
console.log(version.split('(')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.slice** by slicing the string from beginning till `(`

```js
var version = "One Forty Six 1.1 V2 (10 kilo / 20 kilo) (2000 - 2005)";
console.log(version.slice(0, version.indexOf("(")-1)); // -1 is for space before (
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var version = "One Forty Six 1.1 V2 (10 kilo / 20 kilo) (2000 - 2005)";
console.log(version.substring(0, version.indexOf('(')-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
version.substr(0, version.indexOf('('));
```

This should work