# Get part of the current URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

fI'm developing a simple and small search in a Wordpress page using a $_GET variable in the url passed by javascript:

```
<script>
function pesquisar()
{
    var pesquisar = document.getElementById('termo').value;
    var caminho = document.URL+'&pesquisa='+pesquisar;
    window.location = caminho;
}
</script>

<input type='text' id='termo'>
<input type='button' value='pesquisar' onclick='pesquisar()'>
```

So, the url to search is: MYURL/?page_id=51&pesquisa=test

Of course, the page_id is variable. If I search again, the URL is going to be: MYURL/?page_id=51&pesquisa=test&pesquisa=new, what is wrong.

How could I get just the MYURL/?page_id=51 using javascript? The window.location.pathname is not what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that searches naively will be vulnerable to problems like this: What if the URL is:

> http://example.com/?pesquisa=test&page_id=51

You need to search for and remove the relevant query parameter:

```
var caminho = document.URL.replace(/([?&])pesquisa=[^&]+&?/,"$1")+"&pesquisa="+pesquisar;
```

Comment: This works, but the '&' is still repeating. What kind of rule is this? Is this something like preg-match?

Comment: Ah yeah... well, I guess you could add an additional `.replace(/&$/,'')` to remove it. And if you want to liken it to PHP, it's basically `preg_replace`.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks. I'll learn about these rules. I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully it should work

```
<script>
function pesquisar()
{
    var pesquisar = document.getElementById('termo').value;
    var caminho = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname+'&pesquisa='+pesquisar;
    window.location = caminho;
}
</script>

<input type='text' id='termo'>
<input type='button' value='pesquisar' onclick='pesquisar()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var a = document.URL;
    var result = a.substr(0, a.indexOf('&'));
```

Resources:

- [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)
- [how to grab substring before a specified character jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_query_param(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (get_query_param("page_id") != null) {
        alert(window.location.pathname + "?page_id=" + get_query_param('page_id'));
    }
}
</script>
```

hope that helps.