# jQuery selecting a character inside a string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So i have a div that contains the text "12:00PM" .. it's a little clock application.

```
<div id="#clock">12:00PM</div>
```

I wanted to make the ":" part disappear and then reappear..

I wonder if this was possible w/ jQuery.

i have all the intervals and everything worked out... my clock gets updated.. but i just need a way to target/select that ":" character.. and remove it.. and then replace it :)

Is this possible without being too complicated?

Thanks

Comment: `<div id="#clock">12<span class="blink">:</span>00PM</div>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grab substring before a specified character jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/2YqpW/)

**HTML** is unchanged

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$clock = $("#clock");
$blink = true;
setInterval(function(){
    if ($blink) {
        $clock.html($clock.html().replace(":",'<span class="hidden">:</span>'));
        $blink = false;
    }
    else {
        $clock.html($clock.html().replace('<span class="hidden">:</span>',":"));
        $blink = true;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon nice (:

Answer (score 2):

Html:

```
<div id="#clock">12<span id="clock-colon">:</span>00PM</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#clock-colon').hide() // do what you want
```

Comment: should use `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` or the text will move.

Comment: well, I don't know what he wants to do with the colon so I just put `hide()`

Comment: also instead of hide we can use `fadeIn` `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be the same character, use the search() or indexOf() methods and then substring() and concatenation to eliminate the character.