# What is the different between substr and substring?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between substr and substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring)

I just want to clarify this differences of:-

```
alert("abc".substr(0,2));
alert("abc".substring(0,2));
```

the above case both will return

`ab`

```
alert("abc".substr(1,2));
alert("abc".substring(1,2));
```

and the above case will return first `bc` and the second one `b`

so basically for the `substr` the second argument is the length it has to go?
and for `substring` it will stop but not include??

Please correct me if I'm wrong because we will have a quiz today and I don't want to get this wrong again.

Comment: You know there's a site called google, right? [first hit](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/substring-vs-substr-The-Difference-Between-JavaScript-String-Functions.aspx)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for reminding me of that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)'s second parameter is the length of the required substring while [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)'s is a character index, a fact which is pretty trivial to find via a web search.

What is less well-known is that `substr()` is non-standard (up to and including ECMAScript 5; ES3 and ES5 have non-normative sections on `substr()`) and had some bugs in older versions of IE. Also, [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is preferable to `substring()` because it allows negative character indices, counted backwards from the end of the string:

```
alert( "Dandelion".slice(-4) ); // Alerts "lion"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `substring` goes to an index while `substr` goes a length.

Answer (score 1):

As per the following link:

http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/

`Substr` takes a starting index and the length of the string you are trying to segment

`Substring` takes a starting index and the index up to which you want it to segment the string