# JavaScript substr versus substring when starting at the first character

Tags: javascript

> The second argument to substring is the index to stop at (but not
>   include), but the second argument to substr is the maximum length to
>   return.

If starting at the first character in a string, is there any preference to using `substr(0,n)` over 
`substring(0,n)`?

Comment: found this http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/substring-substr-slice-javascript/

Comment: Also might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring

Comment: @pleasedontbelong.  So, substring is preferred, and slice is maybe more preferred.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *real* difference between the two is that `substr()` is non-standard<sup>1</sup>, while `substring()` are standard built-in functions, ignoring differences when the starting index is not 0.

`slice()` is also very similar, but allows negative end indices (number from end, which `substring()` does not allow).

<sup><sup>1:</sup>`substr()` is not officially standard, though pretty much all browsers support it. For compatibility reasons, the standardising committee provides a "recommended" way of implementing this non-standard function, but it's not part of the official standard.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that substr() was non-standard.  How does one know what is standard versus non-standard?

Comment: @user1032531: it's _almost_ standard, but not officially so (though pretty much all browsers support it).  For compatibility reasons, the standardising committee provides a "recommended" way of implementing this non-standard function, but it's not part of the official JavaScript standard.  You can find out by reading [the ECMAScript Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) (yes, big mouthful) - that's the official standard for the JavaScript language.

Comment: Thanks again.  I looked at the spec.  Quite a document.  I will take your word for which one is the standard!

Comment: @user1032531: another resource, a bit less of a mouthful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr  It says that it's never been in, but there is a section saying how it would be "nice" to do it.