# How to remove "/" in JavaScript location.pathname return value

Tags: javascript, url, replace

I request the javascript guru masters again!

Okay this is probably simple, blowing my mind atm.

Example: http://example.com/page.php

```
var path = location.pathname;
```

Returns: /page.php

I would like it to not include the first / so it would return page.php

Thank you guru masters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use one of the several substring functions.

```
var path = location.pathname.substr(1);
```

---

**Update**:
`substr` is now a deprecated method, so you should use `slice` instead.

```
var path = location.pathname.slice(1);
```

Comment: No problem. Here is an interesting link to tell you the difference (in your case, not necessary) between the methods that do the same thing: substr(), substring(), slice(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring

Answer (score 2):

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` function also, but it replaces the all found forward slashes in path.

```
var path = location.pathName.replace("/","");
```

Comment: It doesn't it just replace the first actually.