# Javascript: NaN Error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nan

When the for loop runs the first time everything works fine but the second time the loop runs it isn't working it says "NaN" and at the 3rd time the loop runs it allways write the number of the second loop! I don't know what to do!

```js
function encrypt() {
  var zwischentext = document.querySelector("#text").value;
  var keys = document.querySelector("#key").value;
  var number1 = "";
  var number2 = "";
  var number3 = "";

  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('a', 'g'), "01 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('b', 'g'), "02 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('c', 'g'), "03 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('d', 'g'), "04 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('e', 'g'), "05 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('f', 'g'), "06 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('g', 'g'), "07 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('h', 'g'), "08 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('i', 'g'), "09 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('j', 'g'), "10 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('k', 'g'), "11 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('l', 'g'), "12 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('m', 'g'), "13 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('n', 'g'), "14 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('o', 'g'), "15 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('p', 'g'), "16 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('q', 'g'), "17 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('r', 'g'), "18 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('s', 'g'), "19 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('t', 'g'), "20 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('u', 'g'), "21 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('v', 'g'), "22 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('w', 'g'), "23 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('x', 'g'), "24 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('y', 'g'), "25 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('z', 'g'), "26 ");

  document.querySelector("#output").value = "";

  for (i = 0; i < zwischentext.length; i += 3) {
    number1 = "";
    number2 = "";
    number3 = "";
    number1 = zwischentext.substring(i, 2);
    number2 = keys.substring(i, 2);
    if (number1.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
      number1 = number1.replace("0", "");
    }
    number1 = parseInt(number1);
    if (number2.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
      number2 = number2.replace("0", "");
    }
    number2 = parseInt(number2);
    number3 = number1 + number2;
    console.log("\"" + number3 + "\"");
    document.querySelector("#output").value = (document.querySelector("#output").value + number3 + " ");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>En/Decrypter
    <h1>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="key" id="key" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onclick="encrypt()" type="button" name="verschlüsseln" id="encrypt">ENCTYPT</button>
        <button type="button" name="entschlüsseln" id="decrypt">DECRYPT</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="output" id="output" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `keys.substring(i, 2);` won't work well if `keys` is shorter than `zwischentext`.

Comment: What is the user supposed to put in the `key` input field?

Comment: If I write in the first textarea "abc" and in the second "11 11 11" it should work but it doesnt!

Comment: The user is supposed to put numbers in keys field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.substr()`, not `.substring()`. See [What is the difference between substr and substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring)

```js
function encrypt() {
  var zwischentext = document.querySelector("#text").value;
  var keys = document.querySelector("#key").value;
  var number1 = "";
  var number2 = "";
  var number3 = "";

  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('a', 'g'), "01 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('b', 'g'), "02 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('c', 'g'), "03 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('d', 'g'), "04 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('e', 'g'), "05 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('f', 'g'), "06 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('g', 'g'), "07 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('h', 'g'), "08 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('i', 'g'), "09 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('j', 'g'), "10 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('k', 'g'), "11 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('l', 'g'), "12 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('m', 'g'), "13 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('n', 'g'), "14 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('o', 'g'), "15 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('p', 'g'), "16 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('q', 'g'), "17 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('r', 'g'), "18 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('s', 'g'), "19 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('t', 'g'), "20 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('u', 'g'), "21 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('v', 'g'), "22 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('w', 'g'), "23 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('x', 'g'), "24 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('y', 'g'), "25 ");
  zwischentext = zwischentext.replace(new RegExp('z', 'g'), "26 ");
  console.log(zwischentext);
  document.querySelector("#output").value = "";

  for (i = 0; i < zwischentext.length; i += 3) {
    number1 = "";
    number2 = "";
    number3 = "";
    number1 = zwischentext.substr(i, 2);
    number2 = keys.substr(i, 2);
    console.log("n2 = ", number2);
    if (number1.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
      number1 = number1.replace("0", "");
    }
    number1 = parseInt(number1);
    if (number2.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
      number2 = number2.replace("0", "");
    }
    number2 = parseInt(number2);
    number3 = number1 + number2;
    console.log('"' + number3 + '"');
    document.querySelector("#output").value = (document.querySelector("#output").value + number3 + " ");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>En/Decrypter
    <h1>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="key" id="key" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onclick="encrypt()" type="button" name="verschlüsseln" id="encrypt">ENCTYPT</button>
        <button type="button" name="entschlüsseln" id="decrypt">DECRYPT</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="output" id="output" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
</body>

</html>
```