# How to work with attribute of html elemnt when html is stored in variable

Tags: jquery

here is my sample html which is stored in a variable.

```
var sHtml=''
sHtml='<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test1.gif" /></div>';
sHtml=sHtml + '<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test2.gif" /></div>';
sHtml=sHtml + '<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test3.gif" /></div>';
```

now i want to know how could i add another attribute called delaySrc to all the images which is stored as html in a variable.

please help me to achieve it using jquery. thanks

Comment: This is a bit similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index
Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(sHtml).find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('delaySrc', 'something');
    alert($(this).prop('delaySrc')); // just for ensure
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VSttS/6/)**

Comment: thanks for your code....can i write this way  $(sHtml).find('img').each(function() {
     var img = $(this);
     img.attr("data-original", img.attr("src"));
     alert(img.attr("src")); // just for ensure
});