# Insert text in javascript textbox on correct position

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: How can I insert a string at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

Let's say I have this in my textbox:

```
'My name is John'
```

I want to insert this text: 'Johnson '

to index=11 in the textbox so that it looks like this:

```
'My name is Johnson John'
```

How to do this?

Comment: This is a simple task, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another *just-for-fun* solution:

```
var index = 11,
    word  = "Johnson ";

"My name is John".replace(/./g, function(v, i) {
    return i === index - 1 ? v + word : v;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the value with jquery's `.val()`, then break that apart at your desired position with `.slice(11)`, concatenate with your new text, and put it back into the textbox with `.val(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new prototype called splice

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
```

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yFsNS/)