# Best way to insert char in specific points of string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following string

```
"[Blah][Something.][Where.]"
```

What is the best way to locate wherever the "][" is and add a " + " in between them?

In other words, the resulting string should be:

```
"[Blah] + [Something.] + [Where.]"
```

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index

This was already posted in the past.

Comment: Damascusi isn't asking about inserting characters as specific string indices, but rather, finding a pattern and replacing it with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions...

```
var str = "[Blah][Something.][Where.]"
var newString = str.replace(/\]\[/g, ']+[');
```

[Relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRPfM/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
var string = "[Blah][Something.][Where.]".split("][").join("] + [");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tDFh3/4/

If it was not a constant string, I would fallback to a regular expression and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expresions to find ][ and then add +

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex:

- search for `\]\[`
- replace by `] + [`

[Demo](http://regexr.com?334un)