# How to add a space in a specific index of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a text without spaces, for example:

> thiswebsiteisblockedbytheadministrator

I have to have a space on the 25th index. This is not a replacement Instead just adding a space.

Comment: I myself don't try any of them, but I'm pretty sure you can find an answer from these questions.



 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881836/best-way-to-insert-char-in-specific-points-of-string-in-javascript

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks Quv. Seems okay.