# Insert Character Before 6th Character From Last Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need re-organize price string first value is 1.778,81 i need last value 2.099,00 the code belove results like 2099,00  i need . before 6th character from last.

```
$.each($(".indirimsiz_urun_fiyati span"), function(index) { 
    var KDVsiz = $(this).html().replace('&nbsp;TL + KDV', '');
    var KDVsiz = (KDVsiz).replace(/\./g,"");
    var KDVsiz = (KDVsiz).replace(/,/g,".");
    var KDVsiz = (parseFloat(KDVsiz,10) * 1.18).toFixed(2);
    var KDVsiz = (KDVsiz).replace(/\./g,",");
    $(this).text( KDVsiz + ' TL' );
});
```

Comment: If you had googled you would probably have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4313841/781965):

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
KDVsiz = KDVsiz.splice( KDVsiz.length - 6, 0, "." );
```

I think that should work, but I'm way too lazy to test this out, so if someone feels like correcting me I'll edit/remove my answer.

Of course you can inline that:

```
KDVsiz = KDVsiz.slice(0,KDVsiz.length - 6) + "." + KDVsiz.slice(KDVsiz.length - 6);
```

Sandeep's answer is nicer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
    var b=KDVsiz;

    var a= b.substring(0,b.length-7) + '.' + b.substring(b.length-7);
    alert(a);
```

Comment: Thanx man i changed the line like this;

var KDVsiz = (KDVsiz).substring(0,KDVsiz.length-6) + '.' + (KDVsiz).substring(KDVsiz.length-6);

and its ok now.