# vb6's mid equivalent for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

in vb6 there was a very handy function for string manipulation which could put a character at a certain position of another string and i'm looking for an extended jquery equivalent.

let's say i'm having this string:

```
var mystring = "__1__";
```

when applying the function:

```
var mystring = mid(mystring,4,"x");
```

it should return `__1x_`

another example:

```
var mystring = "";
var mystring = mid(mystring,5,"x");
```

should return: `____5`

i know it requires string manipulation using substr but i was wondering if there's a more elegant way?
thanks

Comment: You use pure Javascript, not jQuery. Please check the following question, which has already been answered: [JavaScript: How can I insert a string at a specific index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: Are you talking about this function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx I'm not familiar with the inserting behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simulated in several ways although there is no such specific function (splice is standard only on Arrays, not Strings).

The easiest one-expression way I know of is with a `String.replace` when adding to a location "past the end of the string" is not required. Of course `String.slice` is also a perfectly valid approach, and may be arguably easier to understand.

```
mystring = "__1__"
// where 3 represents the "characters to skip before inserting"
// and 1 represents the "number of characters to replace"
midstr = mystring.replace(/([^]{3})[^]{0,1}/, "$1x")
```

Neither the above nor a basic slice will work like the 2nd example without additional prepend-as-needed logic.