# Insert new tags in html head with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to insert new tags in html head. Not in document, in string that contains html. So regular expression is only way.

```
<head>
<title>Html</title>
</head>
```

And get something like this:

```
<head>
<title>Html</title>
<script src="some_path.js"></script>
</head>
```

And more:

```
<head>
<title>Html</title>
<script src="some_path.js"></script>
<script src="some_path_2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: `<head>` is a tag just like any other in page...no need for regex. You can append to it

Comment: Since this is not DOM parsing but string parsing, how about avoiding the regexes, and parse out the string instead? A simple tokenizer would do wonders.

Comment: What is your context where you have no access to the DOM?

Comment: The best solution so far.

var wholeHtml = "<head><meta charset='utf-8'></head>";  
    wholeHtml.replace(/(<head.*\><meta.*>)(<\/head>)/g, '$1<script src="some_path.js"><\/script>$2');

Comment: @AntonAleksandrovichTrofimenk - That's really not the best solution, it relies on there being a meta tag immediately after some other tag and it's replacing a whole backreference that is completely unnecessary. I would take a look at Michael's solution

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
function injectScript (id, src, async) {
    var js,
    fjs = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    if (document.getElementById(id))
        return;

    js = document.createElement("script");
    js.id = id;
    js.src = src;
    js.type = 'text/javascript';

    if (async) {
        js.async = true;
    }

    fjs.appendChild(js, fjs);
}
```

Will prevent double injection and support asynchronous scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. Just get the `<head>` element and add children to it as usual:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(whatever);
```

For more information on how this works you can google for "Javascript DOM".

Comment: per the OP "Not in document [DOM], in string that contains html."

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the HTML available as a string, and not as a DOM-document, you can do simple insertions prior to the head-close tag without resorting to regexes. The following code makes use of the splice method [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index). It could be made a function instead of a prototype, and have the second parameter removed for our purposes:

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};

var insertTag = function(newTag, html) {
  var end = html.indexOf('</head>');
  return html.splice(end, 0, newTag);
}
```

So if you had

```
var doc = '<head><title>Html</title></head>';
```

and you ran

```
var doc = insertTag('<script src="some_path.js"></script>', doc);
```

You would get

```
<head><title>Html</title><script src="some_path.js"></script></head>
```

The function is simple, and doesn't check for existence of the head-close tag, or any other safety concerns that might need to be taken. It would would with line-breaks, and is just given as a general idea of how to avoid DOM (per question) and regexes (per saving your sanity).

However, if you have a DOM available -- use it.

Comment: Given the very limited scope of the question and the (horrible) requirement to not use DOM, this is probably the simplest possible approach.

Comment: I might even use the the term "dumb" instead of simple. But it does work. For certain limited definitions of term "work."

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'some_path.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of the page into the title head, you can use window.onload before the title tag and it will search the selector to insert into .

In this example we are searching the page for an H3 tag. (Could be h2, h1...)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
[other metas]
<script>window.onload = function(){
var h3Text = document.querySelector("h3").innerText;
return document.querySelector("title").innerHTML = h3Text;
}</script>
<title></title>
</head><body><h3>This Will Go Into the Title Tag</h3>....
```