# js and edit url before loading - how to do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url:

```
www.domain.com/bla/
```

and button in result page:

```
show 10, 20, 50 per page
```

and pagination:

```
1, 2, 3, 5..
```

but once I have clicked `10`, url becomes `www.domain.com/bla/?show=10`, and then if i click page `2`, `show=10` is disappearing and becoming `www.domain.com/bla/?page=2`

I have several solution in js, but what is the best and professional way of doing this?

my code:

```
var show= $('#show').val();
var url = String(window.location);
if(url.indexOf("page") !== -1){
      var newurl = url +'&show='+show;
      $('.entries').html(' ').load(newurl, function(){
              $(this).fadeIn();
       });
}else{
      var newurl = url +'?show='+sortterm;
      $('.entries').html(' ').load(newurl, function(){
              $(this).fadeIn();
       });
}
```

Comment: @rynhe yeah, here it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use JS **`replace`** method

```
var yourURL = "www.domain.com/bla/?page=10";
var newURL = yourURL.replace("?page", "?show"); //returns www.domain.com/bla/?show=10
```

### Updates:

With help of this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314050/1671639), I learned to use the following prototype *to insert a string at a specific index.*

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
```

Using this I have modified the code

```
var url = "www.domain.com/bla/?page=10";
var insertIndex = url.indexOf('page=10'); //get the index of page
var final = url.splice( insertIndex, 0, "page=2&" ).replace('&page', '&show');

console.log(final); //returns www.domain.com/bla/?page=2&show=10
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/L8q3L/1/)

Comment: by the way, i want them both to appear, i dont want to replace. because depending on ``show`` value, i will give number of pages.. or vise verca

Comment: @doniyor `i want them both to appear` can you share an example?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan is guess he wants something like `www.domain.com/bla/?page=2&show=10`

Comment: @Yashhy exactly this is what i want

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan +1 Exactly!!