# add additional folder after up directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, relative-path

I have many database rows that used relative url with one directory up.

How do i change this relative url:

`<a href="../somefolder"></a>`

to

`<a href="../additionalfolder/somefolder"></a>`

FYI: I use jQuery 1.2.6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314050/1355315

Comment: For your own sake, please upgrade your version of jQuery

Comment: At first glance, this task seems really easy to achieve. I'm surprised you didn't find a solution by yourself. Did you try something? Are there particular constraints making this problem complex?

Comment: @wared yes, it's just newbie question :)

Comment: @WildanMuhlis A newbie who do not know Google (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)? I'm joking :D Keep enjoying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('a').attr('href', function(_, href){
    return href.replace(/^\.\./, '../additionalfolder')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the output you expect?

```
 $(function(){
   var $a =$('a');
     var OldUrl =   $a.attr('href');
     var newUrl = OldUrl.replace("../","../additionalfolder/");         
      $a.attr('href', newUrl);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
var strUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
```

this will give you the root folder path now you can concate your database path to this.