# jQuery - add element after text

Tags: jquery, append

i have a navigation with some links:

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>
  <a class="active">linkname</a>
 <li>
</ul>
```

now i need to add extra content directly after "linkname" like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>
  <a class="active">linkname<b class="caret"></b></a>
 <li>
</ul>
```

how can i add elements (div,span,b) directly after specific text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('ul.nav a.active').append('<b class="caret"></b>');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/CWJLh/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.active').html($('a.active').text() + '<b class="caret"></b>');
```

### Updates:

Wonder if this question to be like how to insert an element inbetween the text

```
<a class="active">link<b class="caret">BOLD</b>name</a>
```

So I tried like

```
String.prototype.splice = function (idx, rem, s) {
    return (this.slice(0, idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};

var text = $('a.active').text();
var ind = text.indexOf('name'); //specify where to add the text
var result = text.splice(ind, 0, '<b class="caret">BOLD</b>');
$('a.active').html(result);
```

Got this **`protoype splice`** from [@user113716's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314050/1671639).

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/CWJLh/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.active").append("<b class='caret'></b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`append()` inserts content to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(".nav .active").append("<b class='caret'></b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can work with .append()

like:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a id="myelement" class="active">linkname<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$("#myelement").append("whatever you want to add after linkname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .html() and replace if you need to add the element specifically after a text like linkname

```
$('.active').html(function(){
  return this.innerHTML.replace("linkname","linkname" + '<b class="caret"></b>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUzY3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) like this:

```
$('a.active').append('<b class="caret"></b>');
```

Or like this:

```
var b = '<b class="caret"></b>';
var a = $('a.active');
b.appendTo(a);
```

Or like this:

```
$('a.active').append($('b.caret'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick test shows that this should do the job:

```
var c = '<b class="caret"></b>';
$(".active").append(c);
```

or as a oneliner ...

```
$(".active").append('<b class="caret"></b>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 var ele = document.querySelector("a.active");
     ele.innerHTML += "<b class="caret"></b>";
```

Comment: This is wrong.  your code will create `b` tag after `a`, not within `a`.  Refer [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and the result for your code will be `<a class="active">linkname</a><b class="caret"></b>`