# jQuery append() just after a element,

Tags: jquery, append

I have this html :

```
<div id="idtest">
<h4>click me test</h4>
</div>  
<ul id="collapse-PerfilManage" class="collapse">
     <li><a class="privateMenuLinkJS "><i class="fa  fa-lock"></i> elm1</a></li>
     <li><a class="privateMenuLinkJS inativeLinkCODE"><i class="fa  fa-lock"></i> elm2</a></li>
     <li><a class="privateMenuLinkJS "><i class="fa  fa-lock"></i> elm3</a></li>
     <li><a class="privateMenuLinkJS "><i class="fa  fa-lock"></i> elm4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to append something inside a "li" that has a "a" element with a class "inativeLinkCODE".

To do this I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click ", "#idtest", function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inativeLinkCODE")) {             
            $(this).parent().append("<span>New</span>");
        }
    });    
});
```

The result of this code is:

```
<li><a>elm2</a><span>New</span></li>
```

I would like to have like this:

```
<li><span>New</span><a>elm2</a></li>
```

Just after the tag "li". Any idea how to do that ?
I´ve tried append() and after() and not worked.

Here you have the fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/a7ww6xyL/

These solution do not fit to my situation 
[jQuery - add element after text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630017/jquery-add-element-after-text)
[jQuery: Add element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244605/jquery-add-element-after-another-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried prepend, this might fix your problem? http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
Just change this line:

`$(this).parent().append("<span>New</span>");`

to this

`$(this).parent().prepend("<span>New</span>");`

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7ww6xyL/1/

Answer (score 0):

you should use prepend instead. prepend put before the parent element while append put after the parent element.

```
$(document).on("click ", "#idtest", function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inativeLinkCODE")) {             
            $(this).parent().prepend("<span>New</span>");
        }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just do like that.

```
$(document).on("click ", "#idtest", function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inativeLinkCODE")) {             
            $(this).parent().prepend("<span>New</span>");
        }
    });    
});
```