# Jquery - append element after an element's text with multiple elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is not a duplicate of [jQuery - add element after text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630017/jquery-add-element-after-text), because the element where I want to insert has more elements besides the text, using append places my element in the wrong place.

Suppose I have many elements like:

```
<li class="target-line">
    <blablabla></blablabla>
    <div class="known">...</div>
    Element's text
    <...variable element, can't query it to use .before()></...>
    <more elements/>
</li>
```

And I want to insert a complex element `newElement` (not one that I can just write as a string) right after the `Element's text`.

How can I do it? Answers without Jquery are ok as long as they're simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `contents()` and `filter()`

```js
$('.target-line').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 
      && this.textContent.includes("Element's text") // if text is known
}).after('<div>New Element</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="target-line">
    <blablabla></blablabla>
    <div class="known">...</div>
    Element's text
    <div class="unknown">...</div>
    <div class="unknown2">...</div>
</li>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that "Element's text" varies for each line. But thanks for this

Comment: But considering there is only one text node, it would work without `&& this.textContent.includes("Element's text")`.

Comment: By the way, wouldn't `nodeType === 3` be better? It's an integer, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

Use `.nextSibling`

## Usage:

```
let text = $('.known')[0].nextSibling
$(text).after('<p>New Element</p>')
```

## Demo:

```js
let text = $('.known')[0].nextSibling
$(text).after('<p>New Element</p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="target-line">
    <blablabla></blablabla>
    <div class="known">...</div>
    Element's text
    <div class="unknown">...</div>
    <div class="unknown2">...</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div before the text is known , you can select it, use `.next()` and then append before that:

```
$rows = $("li.target-line div.known") // get the known div
$afterText = $rows.next() //get the first element after the div
$afterText.before(newElement); //insert your element before that
```

Didn't check what could happen if there were no elements after the text. In this case there is always at least one.