# How to convert a globalize format from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, globalization

I have a following code,

```
  var x = "X : 0.0001  Y : Globalize.format(50.635676576567, n2) %"
```

x is a string.

I need to show the x value as ,(need to convert as globalize format)

"**X** : 0.0001  **Y** : 50.63 %"

how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this, parse the string and eval() method, refer below code snippet.

```
var x = "X : 0.0001  Y : Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') %"
var substring = x.substring(x.indexOf('Y') + 4, x.length - 2);
// assign the value after replacing the string
x = x.replace(substring, eval(substring));
console.log(x);
```

But this you need to assign n2 in single quotes or else you can add single quotes by code, for this [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

Answer (score 1):

If you need x only as string and not object you can do the following:

```
var formated = Globalize.format(50.635676576567, n2);
 var x = "X : 0.0001  Y :" + formated + "%"
```

Comment: it can be work. but i need to customized from string.."X : 0.0001  Y : Globalize.format(50.635676576567, n2) %"

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Thanks dudes,

Answer for this query,

```
 var str = "X : 0.0001  Y : Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') %",
     substr;

while (str.indexOf('Globalize.format(') >= 0) {
        substr = str.substring(str.indexOf('Globalize.format('), str.indexOf(")") + 1);
        str = str.replace(substr, eval(substr));
    }
```