# Finding the index of the last import statement

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm reading a file using Node's `fs.readFileSync(file)`. I need to find the index of the last occurrence of an import statement.

The js file that I'm reading will look something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { mount } from 'react-mounter';
import { AppLayout } from '../../ui/layouts/AppLayout';
import HomePage from '../../ui/pages/HomePage';

FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  action() {
    mount(AppLayout, {
      content: (<HomePage />)
    });
  }
});
```

So in this particular case, I would need to find the index of the semi-colon for this import statement: `import HomePage from '../../ui/pages/HomePage';` since it's the last one.

I've looked into `str.lastIndexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])` but it takes a string as the `searchValue`, and in this case I need to pass in a regex.

It seems like I need a regex that will lookup in reverse.

How do I match and get the index of the last occurrence of import?

Comment: Match all of them and get the last item: `input.match(/^import .*/gm).pop()` - https://jsfiddle.net/f6szkm3m/

Comment: I did not pay attention: you need the index of the last `import` - what about https://jsfiddle.net/f6szkm3m/1/? Or `var m = input.match(/^([\s\S]*\n)?import .*/);
if (m){
 document.body.innerHTML = m.index + (m[1] ? m[1].length : 0);
}`

Comment: (Fiddle #2 - https://jsfiddle.net/f6szkm3m/2/)

Comment: So close @WiktorStribiżew! Check this out and open the console: https://jsfiddle.net/0x2pjfom/. You see how it's adding that new import before the last one? I'm trying to add it after the last one

Comment: So, you need to add another `Import` after the last one, right? See https://jsfiddle.net/0x2pjfom/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to find is the last line starting with `import` and insert another line after it. There are several ways.

**Splice & `indexOf`**:

```js
// splice code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314050/3832970
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
var input = "import React from 'react';\nimport { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';\nimport { mount } from 'react-mounter';\nimport { AppLayout } from '../../ui/layouts/AppLayout';\nimport HomePage from '../../ui/pages/HomePage';\n\nFlowRouter.route('/', {\n  name: 'home',\n  action() {\n    mount(AppLayout, {\n      content: (<HomePage />)\n    });\n  }\n});";
var strt = input.lastIndexOf("\nimport ");
strt = input.indexOf("\n", strt+1);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" +  input.splice(strt+1, 0, "import Example from \'../../example\';\n") + "</pre>";
```

Here, `strt = input.lastIndexOf("\nimport ")` finds the last `import`  after a newline and that is followed with a space. Then, the next newline is found and position is incremented with `strt = input.indexOf("\n", strt+1);`. Then we just insert the string with `splice`.

**Regex**:

```js
var input = "import React from 'react';\nimport { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';\nimport { mount } from 'react-mounter';\nimport { AppLayout } from '../../ui/layouts/AppLayout';\nimport HomePage from '../../ui/pages/HomePage';\n\nFlowRouter.route('/', {\n  name: 'home',\n  action() {\n    mount(AppLayout, {\n      content: (<HomePage />)\n    });\n  }\n});";
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"
   + input.replace(/^(?:[\s\S]*\n)?import .*(?:\r?\n|\r)/, 
     '$&import Example from \'../../example\';\n')
   + "</pre>";
```

Here, the regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[\s\S]*\n)?` - an optional sequence of 0+ any characters as many as possible, getting to the last
- `import`  - literal string `import` with a space
- `.*` - followed with 0+ any chars other than a newline (to match the rest of the line)
- `(?:\r?\n|\r)` - matches a linebreak. You may add `?` after this to make sure we match the last line in the string.

In the replacement, I am using `$&`, the backreference to the whole match (it inserts the whole match into the resulting string).

Comment: Explanations added.