# Insert character in string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this date1, I want to insert "-" to make it 2016-09-23. Is anyone know how to do this using javascript?

```
var date1 = "20160923";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that the year is 4 digit and month and day are 2 digit you can use this code

```js
var date1 = "20160923";

var formattedDate = date1.slice(0, 4) + "-" + date1.slice(4, 6) + "-" + date1.slice(6, 8);

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use regex:

```js
var ret = "20160923".replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3");
console.log(ret);
```

/)

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct method for this, you can write your own Method like `InsertAt(char,pos)` using Prototype object [References from *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)*]

```
String.prototype.InsertAt=function(CharToInsert,Position){
     return this.slice(0,Position) + CharToInsert + this.slice(Position)
}
```

Then use it like this

```
"20160923".InsertAt('-',4); //Output :"2016-0923"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date1 is always consistent...

```
var date2 = date1.slice(0, 4) + '-' + date1.slice(4, 6) + '-' + date1.slice(6, 8);
```