# Convert string to string with backslash

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this '\IonSubsystem1TRAN-88252' 
and I want to convert it to string like this: '\IonSubsystem1\TRAN-88252'.

How do I add the backslashes in the right spots in a generic way?

Comment: what do you mean by right spots ?? after 1 ?

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index]

Answer (score 1):

For this example the easiest way would be to use the `.replace` function.

```
newString = string.replace('IonSubsystem1', 'IonSubsystem1\\');
```

Keep in mind that you need `\\` since a single Backslash is interpreted as a escape character.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I'd do it is by making the substring of the given string using javascript's [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method and appending an additional "/" after it.That is storing the acquired substr in a variable and + "/" after it.But again it depends how generic you want it to be.