# How to insert a string in a specific place in another string that will work with a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have tried various different `string.insert(i, s)` functions but none of them have worked with the loop that I have. Here is an example of my code:

```
var str = "  absolutely  pie";
var indices = [0, 12, 16]; // indices where I want to insert
var things = ["I", "love", 1]; // things I want to insert
for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    str = str.splice(indices[i], 0, things[i]);
}
```

This doesn't work. It's supposed to print out "**I absolutely love pie1**" , but instead it prints out:

**"I  absolutellove1y  pie"**

You can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxdjpgjw/).

I have tried most of the examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index) question.

So what's the problem (is it how the insert methods are implemented?), and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the number of additional `things` that have been inserted in your `string` already by adding `i` to each index. Also note that you have one too many spaces at the beginning of your original `string`; it should be `' absolutely  pie'` instead of `'  absolutely  pie'`.

Make sure that you convert your string to an array of characters (using `String#split`) before trying to call `splice` on it, because `splice` only works on arrays. You can then turn this array back into a string using `Array#join`.

```js
var string = ' absolutely  pie'
var indices = [0, 12, 16]
var things = ['I', 'love', 1]

string = string.split('')

things.forEach(function (e, i) {
  string.splice(indices[i] + i, 0, e)
})

string = string.join('')

console.log(string) //=> 'I absolutely love pie1'
```

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is that the indices you start with are relative to the original string. Inserting '1' at index 16 makes sense at first, but then you add 5 more characters so the actual index you want is 21. The easy fix here is to add an offset:

```
var str = "  absolutely  pie";
var indices = [0, 12, 16]; // indices where I want to insert
var things = ["I", "love", "1"]; // things I want to insert
var offset = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
  str = str.splice(indices[i] + offset, 0, things[i]);
  offset += things[i].length
}
```

The other issue is that if your target is `"I absolutely love pie1"`, it some of the cases you're replacing the space in the original string an in others you're not. Testing my function with a `1` for the `delCount` param, I got `I absolutely lovepie1`. You need an extra "replacement space" between "absolutely" and "pie", or to remove it from the start and pass 0 as `delCount` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating the indexes based on the original string, but you need to take its modifications into account, it grows as the loop progresses.

Simply change the `indices` array to:

```
var indices = [0, 14, 22]; // indices where I want to insert
```

Comment: this is fine, but requires calculating each new index by hand (by adding the length of the previous `thing`. Why not leave that to the code?