# Add new Param URL in the middle using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, redirect

Sorry for asking simple questions. 
I have url with like this :

> http://sub.maindomain/page/title

I want to add

> /en/

in the middle of my url so it will be change to

> http://sub.maindomain/en/page/title

thank you for your help

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How can I insert a string at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str='http://sub.maindomain/page/title';
var en='en/';
var position= str.indexOf('page')
alert(str.substr(0, position) + en + str.substr(position));
```

i guess there will be always page in that url so i found it's index,

and added **`en`** before it's index

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the actual URL with a new URL parameter **en** in the address bar. You can try this.

```
var newUrl = location.origin + '/en' + location.pathname
document.location.href = newUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you're in a context where `document` is available (since your post is taggued `jQuery`, it's most likely the case):

```js
const href = 'http://sub.maindomain/page/title?foo=bar#hash';

// Build a link element
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = href;

// Add '/en' before its pathname
const result = link.protocol + '//' + link.host + '/en' + link.pathname + link.search + link.hash;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if **page** is not on after domain some other string is there then try below code.

```
var str = 'http://sub.maindomain/page/title';
var arr = str.split(/\//);
arr.splice(3, 0, 'en');
str = arr.join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = "http://sub.maindomain/page/title";
let textToAdd = "en/";
//Split the url string into array of two elements and then join them together with a new string 'en/page' as a separator
let newUrl = url.split('page').join(`${textToAdd}page`);
console.log(newUrl);
```