# javascript: IE alternative to convert ISO to local time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert ISO time local time.

here is my code :

```
var local_date = new Date('2018-09-11T06:22:39.000-0400');
local_date.toLocaleDateString();
local_date.toLocaleTimeString();
```

this code is working fine in chrome but in IE its giving error.
first line of code gives me `Invalid Date`

Looking for a fix which works in all browsers.

FYI: I do not want to use moment.js or any other library, want it in vanilla javascript.

Comment: I think people down vote you because you didn't provide the error.

Comment: I have given the error , IE gives me "Invalid Date"

Comment: Dude, I know... I posted you an answer, read it...

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is your date-string format.

By reading the Mozilla documentation about the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) we can see that your string has to follow the [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and the [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

If we open the second one (the [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)) we can see that the accepted format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` where the `Z` may be `(+|-)HH:mm`.

So instead of `new Date('2018-09-11T06:22:39.000-0400');` if we execute `new Date('2018-09-11T06:22:39.000-04:00');` it works.

If you don't want to add it manually, you can do it automatically by using the `splice` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314050/3709257) and the code:

```
// A nice Polyfill
if (!String.prototype.splice) {
    String.prototype.splice = function(start, delCount, newSubStr) {
        return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
    };
}

// Your code
var dateString = '2018-09-11T06:22:39.000-0400'.splice(26, 0, ":");
var local_date = new Date(dateString);
local_date.toLocaleDateString();
local_date.toLocaleTimeString();
```

---

I don't claim that `2018-09-11T06:22:39.000-0400` is in an invalid format, but an unaccepted by the IE.

Also, if you want to `vanilla javascript` you should stop opening IE at all.