# Add string in image url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have image url like
`https://lipsum.mobi/catalog/product/SE0229E/YG/AAA/4/1/SE0229E-YG-AAA-4.jpg`' and need to add `240x240` in that url.

Current Url:
`https://lipsum.mobi/catalog/product/SE0229E/YG/AAA/4/1/SE0229E-YG-AAA-4.jpg`

Expected Output: `https://lipsum.mobi/catalog/product/240x240/SE0229E/YG/AAA/4/1/SE0229E-YG-AAA-4.jpg`

Is there any easy way to do in javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. Just learn how use regular expression

Comment: hi @Anush Kumar, the image is rendered by its pathname, if you need to change the original path of the image, it won't render it throws  404 Not found. so it's better to create a folder 240x240 after the product folder and then keep remain thing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URLs are always starting with the same category / prefix like "https://lipsum.mobi/catalog/product" or just have the same amount of characters, [there is a topic explaining how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)