# React Localization Dynamic String

Tags: reactjs, localization

I have a problem. I want to add total value in local string dynamicly.There is a space in local string.

```
page_title: `Toplamda    adet ******* eğitmeni listeleniyor.`,
```

I have a total value.

```
let total = teachers.length
```

I want to add total value in localization string's space.

```
<p className="mt-0 font-bold text-center max-w-lg mx-auto px-5">
    {`${strings.teachers.teachers_list.page_title}`}
 </p>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation you need to insert value into string at specific index.
You can find here example
[Insert a string at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

The other way is very primitive but it will work in your case. As I see you have 3-4 blank spaces together, you can split string by spaces and then join them back together.

```
const message = 'Hello   world in person'
let test = message.split('   ')
let num = 5
let result = test[0] + " " + num + " " + test[1]
console.log(result)
```

You can modify you existing variable  **strings.teachers.teachers_list.page_title** or you can make new one from it and work on it. Its up to you.