# javascript replace character at index problem

Tags: javascript, string

I have my replaceAt method look like something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, c) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + c + this.substr(index+c.length);
}
```

I have a trim at function which removes whitespace starting at a specific index from a string that looks like this:

```
String.prototype.startTrimAt = function(i) {
    var string = this;
    while (string.charAt(i) == ' '){
        string = string.replaceAt(i, '');
    }
    return string;
};
```

So this function would work like this:

```
"(  tree)".startTrimAt(1); //returns (tree)
```

The problem i am having is that it just loops in the startTrimAt function and I am not sure why. Any help would be appricated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replaceAt() method doesn't seem right for empty string.

Try

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, c) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + c + this.substr(index + (c.length == 0 ? 1 : c.length));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your replaceAt does not work as you expect when the second argument is a zero-length string:

```
"( tree)".replaceAt(1,'')//returns "(  tree)"
```

Remember, you're replacing the same number of characters as the string in your second argument. When that string has length zero, you replace zero characters.

Since the string isn't actually altered, character 1 is always ' ', hence your infinite loop.

Note that

```
"( tree)".substr(0,1) //returns "("
```

and

```
"( tree)".substr(1,6) //returns " tree)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `replaceAt` method doesn't work well.  The length of the empty string `''` is 0, so it's returning `substr(0, 1)` and `substr(1)` which is equivalent to the original string `( tree)` hence the loop.  Since you're giving a single index parameter I assume you're only ever replacing a single character, so your `replaceAt` method should be:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, c) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + c + this.substr(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing one character at a time is inefficient. You can make use of regexes to replace all spaces at once.

```
String.prototype.startTrimAt = function(i) {
    return this.substr(0,i) + this.substr(i).replace(/^ +/, '');
};
```

Or:

```
String.prototype.startTrimAt = function(i) {
    var re = new RegExp('^(.{'+i+'}) +');
    return this.replace(re, '$1');
};
```