# How can i match and replace a string and its before one letter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var str="itss[BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK] it's a test stringgg[BACK][BACK]";
var word = '[BACK]';
var substrings = str.split(word);
var cnt= substrings.length - 1;
for(var i = 0;i<cnt;i++){
  str = str.replace(/.{1}\[BACK\]{1}/i,""); //remove backspace and one character before it.
}
```

The above script returns something like "[BACK it's a test string" I need to get this result as "it's a test string" please help me....

Comment: Am i right when saying you want to emulate a backspace keystroke with regex? So for every single [BACK] instance a leading character is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do this without a regex actually.

```
String.prototype.replaceFromIndex=function(index, length, replace) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replace + this.substr(index+length);
}

var search = '[BACK]';
var str="itss[BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK] it's a test stringgg[BACK][BACK]";

while((index = str.indexOf(search)) >= 0){
    str = str.replaceFromIndex(index-1, search.length+1, '');    
}

alert(str);
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/fRThH/2/ for a working example.
Wrap it in a function and you are ready to go!

Courtesy to Cem Kalyoncu ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/187018 ) for a slightly modified version of `String.prototype.replaceAt`

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to count all the backspaces `[BACK]` and then replace them with an empty string one by one:

```
var str="itss[BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK] it's a test stringgg[BACK][BACK]";

var backspaces = str.match(/\[BACK\]/g).length;

for(i=0; i<backspaces; i++)
{
    str = str.replace(/.?\[BACK\]/, '');
}
document.write( str );
```

working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQUnJ/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
var dat = str.split('[BACK]').filter(function(e){return e})[1];
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qccqp/) is the working demo.

Comment: not really what OP wants, and it doesn't show "it's a test string", but "it's a test stringgg"

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that I found out was that you didn't set a condition in which you would not have to remove the first character when the string `'[BACK]'` is in position zero.

Well, the solution I am posting here first search for the position of the first `'[BACK]'` string, and then creates a substring of the characters that we want to remove, so, if there is a character before the string `'[BACK]'`, it is included in the substring. Then, the substring is removed from the main string, and it continues looping until all the `'[BACK]'` s are removed.

```
var str = "itss[BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK][BACK] it's a test stringgg[BACK][BACK]";
var word = '[BACK]';
var substrings = str.split(word);
var cnt = substrings.length - 1;
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    pos = str.search("[BACK]");
    if (pos - 1 > 0) {
        str = str.replace(str.substring(pos - 2, pos + 5), '');
    } else {
        str = str.replace(str.substring(pos - 1, pos + 5), '');
    }
}
```

[Here is the code in jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/q7kjX/)