# Modifying elements of a string directly

Tags: javascript

I have a string. It's just like;

```
var str = "This is an example sentence, thanks.";
```

I want to change every fifth element of this string.

```
for(var i=5; i<=str.length; i=i+5)
{
   str[i]='X';  // it doesn't work, I need something like that
}
```

So I want str to be "ThisXis aX exaXple XenteXce, XhankX."

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you tried with [concat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) and [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)?

Comment: Could you explain a bit.

Comment: Here is related discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **RegEx**

```
str = str.replace(/(....)./g, "$1X")
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4B63D/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "This is an example sentence, thanks.";

var newString = "";
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
   if ((i % 5) == 4) {
     newString += "X";
   } else {
     newString += str.charAt(i);
   }
}
```

Here is a running example. http://jsfiddle.net/WufuK/1

Comment: +1 but for IE 8 and lower, `str[i]` should be `str.charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.substring()`

```
var a = "This is an example sentence, thanks.";
var result ="";
for(var i=0;i <a.length-1; i+=5){
    result +=a.substr(i, 4)+'X';
}

alert(result)
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVb4u/5

Comment: You may want to take another look at the result in your Fiddle. You should be doing `a.substr(i, 4)+'X'` or `a.substring(i, i+4)+'X'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map, although the regex solution looks better.

```
str = str.split('').map(function(chr, index){
  return (index % 5 === 4)? 'X' : chr;
}).join('');
```

Comment: Note that ie8 and lower doesn't support `map()`.

Comment: ie doesn't support much of anything :(

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses `Array.reduce`, which is native to JavaScript 1.8, but can be [backported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility).

```
Array.prototype.reduce.call("This is an example sentence, thanks.", function(p,c,i,a) { return p + ( i % 5 == 4 ? "X" : c); });
```

**Update:** Updated to reflect **am not i am**'s comments below.

Comment: You probably mean `Array.prototype.reduce.call("This is...)`

Comment: @amnotiam no, I actually meant what I wrote. Your method would work in older versions of JavaScript, but [Array generics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6#Array_and_String_generics) are available in 1.6 and up.

Comment: Well the link in your question links to the compatibility patch for `Array.prototype.reduce`, not `Array.reduce`. Would be a good idea to note that you're referring to that non-ES-standard Mozilla extension. The closest it is to standard right now seems to be [this strawman proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:array_statics).

Comment: @amnotiam Good point, I was misled by the MDN. Normally when something is nonstandard they point it out.