# Javascript sort array and sync over network

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let say Client1 has a big array in browser (javascript). Client2 has the same array.
Now when Client1 click Shuffle button, this array will sort by randomly. The problem is I want to sync this new order to Client2.
The idea is I don't want to send all item over network to Client2 because it's big. Then I think about a function `array.shuffle(n)` where n is a random number. The shuffle function use n to sort array somehow. And when I send `n` to Client2, it call the same function and get the same order of array.
Is there a function like that ?

Comment: You'd need to use server-side coding languages such as PHP or Node.JS

Comment: ok, but how ? can you give me some code

Comment: You can use any shuffle algorithm you want as long as it gets its randomness from a zero-entropy seedable PRNG, like this one: http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html . Just use the same seed in both.

Comment: Here we don't write code for you - we fix code you already have.

Comment: Alternatively you could send the final permutation over the network, a lot more info than a seed, but you can still skip sending all the contents of the array.

Comment: @JackBashford yea. At least give some useful information in your comment. Server side have nothing to do in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm. It shuffles based on random number which you can send to client2 and achieve the same shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

I found it
- [Javascript random ordering with seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801687/javascript-random-ordering-with-seed)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/shuffle-seed
- https://github.com/LouisT/SeededShuffle

Just use the right keyword from @Paulpro comment