# Predictable Javascript array shuffle

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, repeat

I'm trying to predictably shuffle javascript arrays the same way each time the webpage is loaded.

I can shuffle the arrays randomly, but every time i reload the page it's a different sequence.

I'd like it to shuffle the arrays the same way every time the page loads. There are many arrays and they are part of a procedurally generated world.

Comment: Store it in local storage

Comment: Write a not so random script for it.

Comment: Thank you adeneo, but the user can erase local storage as part of the world's options. So i'd like to have some hard code that runs the same each time.

Comment: Aren't procedural generators usually initialized with a seed value so that the random generator produces the same series of values each time?

Comment: Thank you - Yes they are, but I am having trouble applying the world generator to javascript arrays. I will take a another look and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Chance.js worked perfectly. Thank you Billy Moon.

My Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/chance.js"></script>

var chance1 = new Chance(124); // you can choose a seed here, i chose 124
console.log(chance1.shuffle(['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']));
// Array [ "alpha", "delta", "echo", "charlie", "bravo" ]
```

As long as you set the seed with new Chance(xxx) you get the same result every time.

Comment: You saved me hours of research. Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [chancejs.com's `seed`](https://chancejs.com/usage/seed.html) function.

Comment: Thank you Billy Moon. Chance.js worked perfectly. 

var chance1 = new Chance(124); // you can choose a seed here, i chose 124
console.log(chance1.shuffle(['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']));
// Array [ "alpha", "delta", "echo", "charlie", "bravo" ]

Comment: @Protopop yeah - chance.js is very smart, and is great for many other things too - especially for repeatability in testing for example.

Answer (score 5):

In order to shuffle an array in a seemingly random and predetermined way, you can break the problem into two parts.

### 1. Generate pseudo random numbers

You could use a different PRNG, but the [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) is very simple, fast to both initialise and step through, and evenly distributed.

This function takes an integer as a seed value, and returns a random function that always returns the same floating point values in the range 0 to 1.

```
const xor = seed => {
  const baseSeeds = [123456789, 362436069, 521288629, 88675123]

  let [x, y, z, w] = baseSeeds

  const random = () => {
    const t = x ^ (x << 11)
    ;[x, y, z] = [y, z, w]
    w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8))
    return w / 0x7fffffff
  }

  ;[x, y, z, w] = baseSeeds.map(i => i + seed)
  ;[x, y, z, w] = [0, 0, 0, 0].map(() => Math.round(random() * 1e16))

  return random
}
```

### 2. Shuffle using configurable random function

The [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is an efficient shuffle algorithm with even distribution.

```
const shuffle = (array, random = Math.random) => {
  let m = array.length
  let t
  let i

  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(random() * m--)
    t = array[m]
    array[m] = array[i]
    array[i] = t
  }

  return array
}
```

### Putting it together

```
// passing an xor with the same seed produces same order of output array
console.log(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], xor(1))) // [ 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8, 9, 5 ]
console.log(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], xor(1))) // [ 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8, 9, 5 ]

// changing the seed passed to the xor function changes the output
console.log(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], xor(2))) // [ 4, 2, 6, 9, 7, 3, 8, 1, 5 ]
```