# .replace everything past a certain point

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

Is it possible to use `.replace` to change everything beyond `amet` in the sentence above?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

Comment: Replace everything beyond `amet` *with what*?

Comment: Instead of `.replace()`, eaiser to use `s.substr(0, s.indexOf('amet')) + "what you want to add on..."`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is.

```
str.replace(/(amet).+$/, '$1FOO')
```

If `"amet"` actually contains weird characters, you have to 'regex quote' them: `.`, `-`, `[` etc.

**EDIT**
Explaining regex is hard.

- `(amet)` => Capture a literal "amet". Capture, because you want to keep that part for the replacement, because you want to replace everything **after** "amet".
- `.+` => Any type of characters (`.`), but at least one (`+`). If you want at least 0, you can use `*` instead of `+`.
- `$` => the end of the subject (`str`). In thise case, it's unnecessary, because regex is greedy and won't stop until you tell it to (and since `.+` will never stop matching, the end is the end)
- `$1` => This is a placeholder for 'the first match'. In this case, it's awlways `"amet"`, because we matched a literal `"amet"`. If the regex is variable, this `$1` will be unknown (which is what it exists for).
- `FOO` => Another literal (the replacement). Your question includes "... change everything after ..." which - in my eyes - means "replace by `"FOO"`".

Clear enough? If not, I'd be happy to try to explain better. Always a great resource (for young and old, wise and not-so-wise and pro's and beginners): http://www.regular-expressions.info/

To conclude: **regex is AWESOME**.

Comment: Could you explain your regex? From what I can tell it matches, and remembers the match of, `amet`, but what does the rest mean? Particularly the `'$1F00'`?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Can I include `amet` in the replacement without specifying what comes before it?