# Replacing character at a particular index with a string in Javascript , Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript

Is it possible to replace the a character at a particular position with a string

Let us say there is say a string : `"I am a man"`

I want to replace character at 7 with the string `"wom"` (regardless of what the original character was).

The final result should be : `"I am a woman"`

Comment: See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript (you can use the function of the selected answer, works as well for strings).

Comment: @lxx no, that function is no good as it replaces as many characters in the source string as were supplied - the OP here only wants _one_ character replaced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Strings are *immutable* in Javascript - you can't modify them "in place".

You'll need to cut the original string up, and return a new string made out of all of the pieces:

```
// replace the 'n'th character of 's' with 't'
function replaceAt(s, n, t) {
    return s.substring(0, n) + t + s.substring(n + 1);
}
```

NB: I didn't add this to `String.prototype` because on some browsers performance is very bad if you add functions to the `prototype` of built-in types.

Comment: They really are immutable, but that doesn't mean you have to do index math. There is already a replace method. See my reply.

Comment: @Slavo `.replace` doesn't support position based indices, unless you construct a needlessly complicated regexp.

Comment: I agree. The examples given in the question don't need complex RegEx. I guess it all depends on the real use case.

Comment: @Slavo the OP's use case is replacing a character _by index_ - `.replace()` replaces _by content_.  i.e. he wants to replace at the 7th position _regardless of what character is already there_.

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is that his first example can be done by `str.replace("man", "woman");`

Comment: @Slavo _no, it can't_ because the whole point is that he doesn't know a priori that the original content is "man" !  The relevant information is the _character index_, not its _value_!

Comment: @Alnitak. It seems to replace two characters. Otherwise its fine. How can that be solved.

Comment: @BobbyFrancisJoseph I had an unnecessary `-1` in the first `substring()` - should be fine now!  I forgot that substring is _exclusive_ on the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it this way, using array functions.

```
var a='I am a man'.split('');
a.splice.apply(a,[7,1].concat('wom'.split('')));
console.log(a.join(''));//<-- I am a woman
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `string.replace()` method in Javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

P.S.
By the way, in your first example, the index of the "m" you are talking about is 7. Javascript uses 0-based indices.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OP's problem. They want to access by index and string.replace() replaces with a regular expression. This is completely different.