# Using .replace() at a specific index

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

Is there a function that can replace a string within a string once at a specific index? Example:

```
var string1="my text is my text";
var string2="my";
string1.replaceAt(string2,"your",10);
```

and the resultant output would be "my text is your text", Or:

```
var string1="my text is my text";
var string2="my";
string1.replaceAt(string2,"your",0);
```

in which case the result would be "your text is my text".

Comment: `string1 = string1.slice(0,10) + string1.slice(10).replace(string2, "your");` - wrap in a custom `replaceAt()` function if required.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/1757964

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing character at a particular index with a string in Javascript , Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784637/replacing-character-at-a-particular-index-with-a-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 11):

```
function ReplaceAt(input, search, replace, start, end) {
    return input.slice(0, start)
        + input.slice(start, end).replace(search, replace)
        + input.slice(end);
}
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6bq3f6hx/11/)

PS. modify the code to add empty checks, boundary checks etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the "related questions" bar, this old answer seems to be applicable to your case. Replacing a single character (in my referenced question) is not very different from replacing a string.

[How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript?rq=1)